# Late 09 imac new ubuntu install black screen

Tags: grub2

Repurposing old late 09 imac I7 ATI radeon 48xx. 2 TB HHD and 16 GB ram.  Performed the install and went normally.  Problem is when booting up it goes about 5 seconds and screen goes blank.  For the life of me I cannot get the grub loader to come up to edit the proper file to set the mode.  Actually I am trying to use this machine for Video editing exclusively.  Am I wasting my time or is this possible and can you help get my screen issue corrected.
Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu release/version?

Comment: Sorry version 22.04

Comment: It may not make a difference, i.e., solve the problem but for older hardware it's often recommended to use an Ubuntu falvor with a lighter desktop like Xubuntu, Lubuntu, etc.

Comment: Tried mintlinux as well and it does the same thing.  This has to be a driver issue but when you boot to the usb it boots ok.  Once you change the nomodeset.  I just can't get there when booting the actual install.  Any ideas?

Comment: Linux Mint certainly wouldn't make any difference. The recommendation was about **lighter* desktop environments. Why are you using `nomodeset` and when exactly are you adding and removing it?